# How can I connect to a local geth node from docker container?

Tags: go-ethereum

In this case, I run a geth node in local env, and A app in docker,  How can I connect to geth from docker?

Comment: what kind of app are you running in docker ? What's the command you use to launch get and which protocole you want to communicate with ?

Comment: Thx for replying!  I run geth locally in this way:  geth --identity testNode --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --datadir ethereum_private_testnet --port 30303 --nodiscover --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 --networkid 100  , and then I  run a  python app in docker,   I use ethjsonrpc lib, like this ``` >>> from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc  # to use Parity-specific methods, import ParityEthJsonRpc
>>> c = EthJsonRpc('172.24.0.1', 8545)
>>> c.net_version()  ```  , BTW,   I can run it in Mac successfully, but in Linux, it can't work

Answer (score 0):

Default rpc address for geth is set to localhost. You can see which ip and port is used on linux with a tool like `netstat`, default should be 127.0.0.1 .

You can specify the server listening interface with this command `--rpcaddr`

Comment: Yes,  I . specified the rpc interface with --rpcaddr,  like:  `geth --identity "testNode" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir $datadir --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "personal,db,eth,net,web3,admin,txpool,miner" --networkid 100 --mine --etherbase "0xf6de496ec5601d74937ddd77af09c8cd4ba41ab5"`,  but it doesn't work